# pandas read a text file and split the names into columns based on the first character

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi I'm looking to forward to see if we can read a text file and place them into separate columns based on the first character with pandas.

Below is the text file

```
$ cat file.txt
AAAAAA
AAAAAA
AAAAAA
AAAAAA
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
BBBBBB
BBBBBB
BBBBBB
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
CCCCCC
CCCCCC
CCCCCC
CCCCCC
DDDDDD
DDDDDD
DDDDDD
DDDDDD
DDDDDD
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
FFFFFF
FFFFFF
FFFFFF
FFFFFF
FFFFFF
```

### Desired:

```
COL_1   COL_2   COL_3   COL_4   COL_5   COL_6
AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best way:

```
# notice the header=None option
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None)

# extract the first character of the string
df['start'] = df[0].str[0]

# group by the first character of the string
# cumcount gives you the order/rank of the row within its group
df['idx'] = df.groupby('start').cumcount()

# pivot - search StackOverflow for 47152691
df.pivot(index='idx', columns='start', values=0)
```

Output:

```
start       A       B       C       D       E       F
idx                                                  
0      AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
1      AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
2      AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
3      AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
4      AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
```

Comment: This looks to be nice +1, but it throws an error while running. `KeyError: 0 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`  may be due to pandas version difference , mine is `0.21.0`

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared, actually, we should do `df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None)`.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang ... this works now, Would mind explaining the solution, this is help posterity.

Comment: @krock1516 do the added comments help?

Comment: @QuangHoang, really appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

#### `from_dict`

```
d = {}
for line in open('file.txt').read().splitlines():
    d.setdefault(line[0], []).append(line)

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T

        A       B       C       D       E       F
0  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
1  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
2  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
3  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
4  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
```

---

Similarly but without reading in the whole file at once

```
d = {}
for line in open('file.txt'):
    d.setdefault(line[0], []).append(line.strip('\n'))

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be (Assuming `Col` is the column name):

```
m=df.assign(k=(pd.factorize(df.Col)[0]+1).astype(str)).groupby('k')['Col'].apply(list)
pd.DataFrame(m.values.tolist(),index='Col_'+m.index).T
```

---

```
    Col_1   Col_2   Col_3   Col_4   Col_5   Col_6
0  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
1  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
2  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
3  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
4  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
```

Another one without apply:

```
m=(df.assign(k=(pd.factorize(df.Col)[0]+1).astype(str),s=df.groupby('Col').cumcount())
 .set_index(['s','k'])).unstack().rename_axis(None)
m.columns=m.columns.map('_'.join)
```

---

```
    Col_1   Col_2   Col_3   Col_4   Col_5   Col_6
0  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
1  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
2  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
3  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
4  AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEE  FFFFFF
```